# How to identify the same time in both DST / non-DST for iPhone in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, timezone

In swift, the current time `Date()` is retrieved from the system time of iPhone. Using `DateFormatter()` seems to work the same way with a given string. For example, using the following method, we can get the same result as calling `Date()` right when the iPhone time reaches 2018/04/01 02:00:00

```
let MY_DATE_STRING = "2018/04/01 02:00:00"

var resultTime: Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    return formatter.date(from: MY_DATE_STRING)!
}
```

My question is, let's say, if 2018/04/01 2:00:00 is the end of daylight saving time, so the iPhone will have two 2am on that day -- one is with DST, while the other is not. These two times should have different UTC timestamp though. If currently the iPhone(or my self-defined `MY_DATE_STRING`) just enters the second 2am, which is a non-DST one, how could I set the TimeZone or other attributes so that the `Date()` or the given `MY_DATE_STRING` could generate the timestamp of second 2am instead of the first one?